# gsl_vector instead of std::vector

Tags: c++, c, vector, gsl

I want to use the gsl function

`gsl_ran_multivariate_gaussian (const gsl_rng * r, const gsl_vector * mu, const gsl_matrix * L, gsl_vector * result);`

As input I have `std::vector<int>` as a vector and `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` as a matrix.
I have difficulties to convert the std::vector to gsl_vector. I used

```
gsl_vector_int_const_view gslVec = gsl_vector_int_const_view_array(&myVecData[0], myVecData.size());
```

and called the function `gsl_ran_multivariate_gaussian(r, &gslVec.vector, ..., ...);`
but I get error for incompatible types.

How can I create and pass a vector of integers into the 2nd parameter of the gsl_ran_multivariate_gaussian function?

Also, how can I efficiently create gsl_vector from the `std:vector<int>` ?

Comment: Can you provide the compile error ? and by the way, the function gsl_vector_int_const_view_array is not part of gsl itself, is it ? what is this wrapper you are using ?

Comment: The function gsl_vector_int_const_view_array is part of GSL. It is declared in gsl_vector_int.h     The error I get is: The argument of type double is incompatible with parameter of type int. I am working on Windows and installed GSL with vcpkg

Comment: provide a minimal reproducible example. see here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example